# How to get ref from Button by Paper for Reanimated?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-paper

How to get `ref` from Button by Paper for Reanimated?

My code:

```js
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
    
    ...
    
    const MyView = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
        return <Button ref={ref} {...props} />;
    });

    const MyAnimatedView = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(MyView);
```

I get an error:
`Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: This is not a direct solution to the problem, but I haven't found any other way.**

Well, I had to write my own component from scratch.

Something like this:

```js
import { Pressable, Text } from "react-native";
import Animated from "react-native-reanimated";

...

<Pressable>
    <Animated.View style={animatedViewStyle}>
        <Text>Button</Text>
    </Animated.View>
</Pressable>
```